# File or arguments not valid for site template 'visprus#0'.\r\nParameter name: WebTemplate"

Tags: sharepoint

I tried to create a site with "Visio Process Repository" template in **Sharepoint office 365** but got an error saying "File or arguments not valid for site template 'visprus#0'.\r\nParameter name: WebTemplate".

I even Uninstalled the .WSP file and re-installed it but occurred same error.

Code snippet used was as follows:

```
var webCreateInfo = new ClientOM.WebCreationInformation{
            Description = request.Web.Description,
            Language = (int)request.Web.Language,
            Title = request.Web.Title,
            Url = webUrlPart,
            UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = !request.Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
            WebTemplate = request.WebTemplate
        };

        ClientOM.Web oNewWebsite = oWebsite.Webs.Add(webCreateInfo);
        clientContext.Load(
            oNewWebsite,
            website => website.ServerRelativeUrl,
            website => website.Created);
        clientContext.RequestTimeout = 600000;
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please suggest me to resolve the issue.

Regards